# how to exclude one specific date from an SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using this query where I only want to exclude the rows with the date '01-JAN-00' but I am getting the same results without any changes or filtering.

```
SELECT PT.SITE_PROJECTS_ID, WS.WORKSTEP_ID, WS.WORKSTEP_NAME, PTT.TASK_STATUS, PTT.CREATED_DATE, PTT.COMPLETED_DATE,
    sp.SITE_PROJECTS_ID, spm.SITE_INFO_ID, si.SITE_ID, si.CITY, si.STATE, si.ZIP, si.COUNTY
    From site_projects sp
    Inner join site_projects_map spm on spm.site_projects_id = sp.site_projects_id
    Inner join site_info si on si.site_info_id = spm.site_info_id
    INNER JOIN PROJ_TRACKER PT on PT.site_projects_id = sp.site_projects_id
    INNER JOIN PROJ_TRACKER_TASKS PTT ON PT.PROJ_TRACKER_ID = PTT.PROJ_TRACKER_ID
    INNER JOIN WORKSTEPS  WS ON WS.WORKSTEP_ID = PTT.WORKSTEP_ID
    INNER JOIN WORKFLOW WF ON WF.WF_ID = WS.WF_ID
    WHERE PTT.COMPLETED_DATE <> '01-JAN-00'
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: I am getting the same results without any changes, the changes that I want. Basically all the rows without that particular date '01-JAN-00'

Comment: How do the PTT.COMPLETED_DATE dates look? Column data type?

Comment: Yes COMPLETED_DATE is a column basically

Comment: What RDBMS are you working with?

Comment: Oracle sqldeveloper

Comment: Is COMPLETED_DATE a timestamp? Marne trynusing to_date function?

Comment: No I dont think it is a timestamp. It is not in minutes and seconds. It is literally like this '01-JAN-00' nothing else.

Comment: Please check the datatype of Column from ALL_TAB_COLS

Comment: select to_char(COMPLETED_DATE ,'dd-mm-yyyy') from PROJ_TRACKER_TASKS for that particular row where you seeing issue.

Comment: @SyedTahmidHasan `'01-JAN-00'` is just the way SQL Developer formats it for display. Go to Tools > Preferences > Database > NLS and change "Date Format" from `DD-MON-RR` to `DD-MON-RRRR` or `DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The date `'01-JAN-00'` represents 2000-01-01.  You can see this if you run:

```
select to_char(cast('01-JAN-00' as date), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
from dual;
```

(There may be some settings that can affect the century.)

I am guessing that you intend 0000-01-01.  This is a good lesson to always use `date` and `timestamp` constants using the correct formats:

```
WHERE PTT.COMPLETED_DATE = DATE '0000-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You DATE column almost certainly has a time component that you are not seeing due to your session's default format mask.  Try this:

```
WHERE TRUNC(PTT.COMPLETED_DATE) <> '01-JAN-00'
```

That removes the time component.